# Python парсинг html: вытащить данные из ячеек вложенной таблицы

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, lxml

Как с помощью bs4 или lxml получить (вытащить) такую структуру:

```
Наименование; ООО Ромашка
```

из html:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="CompanyInformationPadding" width="98%">
   <tr valign="top">
    <td>
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr valign="top">
       <td style="width:190px;">
        Наименование:
       </td>
       <td>
        ООО Ромашка
       </td>
      </tr>
```

Ниже идут другие параметры, т.е. нужно получить содержимое `<td style="width:190px;">` и следующего `<td>` и так кучу раз

Chrome подсказывает такой селектор

```
#contentPlaceHolder > table.CompanyInformationPadding > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)
```

но по нему не удается ничего найти

Comment: lxml: через xpath `//table[class="CompanyInformationPadding"]`, bs: через css-селектор: `table.CompanyInformationPadding`. Так сможете получить таблицу, если немного модернизируете запросы и включите в запрос `td`, то соберете и нужные вам ячейки

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, что значит, "получить такую же структуру"?

Если конечная цель это текст из `td` тэгов, то его можно получить так:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
html = '''<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="CompanyInformationPadding" width="98%">
   <tr valign="top">
    <td>
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr valign="top">
       <td style="width:190px;">
        Наименование:
       </td>
       <td>
        ООО Ромашка
       </td>
      </tr>'''


td_contents = []
soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'CompanyInformationPadding')
internal_table = table.find('table')

for td in internal_table.find_all('td'):
    td_contents.append(td.text.strip())
```

Comment: перечитал вопрос, осознал, что изначально неправильно его понял. Переделал решение в соответствии с вопросом.

Comment: @ss_beer, дадите какой-нибудь фидбэк? мое решение помогло решить проблему?